# Weird jquery iframe height display

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have following method called on iframe load:

```
function resizeIframe() {    
    $("#content").css("height", "");
    $("#content").css("width", "");
    var iFrameHeight = $('iFrame').contents().height();
    var iFrameWidth = $('iFrame').contents().width();

    $("#content").css("height", iFrameHeight);
    $("#content").css("width", iFrameWidth);
}
```

When this is called there is lot of empty space below the text so iframe height is around 1457px. But strange thing is when i add alert like this:

```
function resizeIframe() {    
    $("#content").css("height", "");
    $("#content").css("width", "");

    var iFrameHeight = $('iFrame').contents().height();
    var iFrameWidth = $('iFrame').contents().width();

    alert($("#content").height()); <-------------this alert

    $("#content").css("height", iFrameHeight);
    $("#content").css("width", iFrameWidth);
}
```

After adding this alert it fits to content size of 1050px. I am totally confused why is it doing that or how to fix this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you include two demos in your answer (using http://jsfiddle.net/, for example). Also, remove the typo from your question's title. It should be `Weird`, not `Wierd`. Even better, choose a more descriptive title.

Comment: When are you calling that method?

Comment: @KevinB - here is how it is called: $(document).ready(function () {
$("#iFrame").load(function () { resizeIframe(); });
}

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you need to set the size for the `iFrame` in the parent page. If you don't, it will take the full width and height of the parent container and set this size for the framed window.
So `$('iFrame').contents().height()` will return the actually rendered height, which you already know.

I don't understand your intention with these codes.

If you want to check the original dynamic size of the framed page, this could be hard. I don't have any ideas for this yet.

Edit: You might use scripts like this one to fix the dynamic size issue.
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/iframessi2.htm